# Why can't I change permissions on config.php or database.php?

Tags: permissions

I am in the process of completing an upgrade to EE 2.6.1 and I am unable to change the file permissions on config.php, database.php or cache.

I make the changes and it just bounces back. The Owner and Group appear to be okay in the file info. Any clues why this may be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: I had this happen before and it took an os restart or ftp program restart - worth a try.

Comment: I both relaunched Transmit and rebooted and still get the same results.

Comment: For me it was because of SELinux, security enhanced linux, http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/32161/3790

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading the files, or renaming them to something else.
Then create 2 new files directly on the server and copy/paste the contents of the original files into the new files.

Since you created the files, you *should* be able to then change the permissions of them.

Comment: I tried this and the new file I created did the same thing. I tried to apply 666 and it reverted back to 644.